# Multiple instances of simple modal popup on one page

Tags: jquery, popup, simplemodal

I'm trying to create multiple instances of the simple modal popup on a single page.

When clicking a button with the class "popup_button" all popups with the class "popup_content" are opened at the same time
http://jsfiddle.net/A96su/

```
$('.popup_button').click(function (e) {
$('.popup_content').modal({
    closeClass: "popup_close",
    closeHTML: "<a href='#'>Close</a>",
    position: [36,238]
    });

    return false;
});
```

I was trying to work with closest(), but the plugin still opens all instances of "popup_content" at the same time
http://jsfiddle.net/A96su/1/

```
$('.popup_content').closest('.popup_button').click(function (e) {
$('.popup_content').modal({
    closeClass: "popup_close",
    closeHTML: "<a href='#'>Close</a>",
    position: [36,238]
    });

    return false;
});
```

I would appreciate your help!
-n-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.popup_button').click(function (e) {
    $('.popup_content', this).modal({
        closeClass: "popup_close",
        closeHTML: "<a href='#'>Close</a>",
        position: [36,238]
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Draw your attention on this line: `$('.popup_content', this)`